# All numbers from $1$ to $150$ (in decimal system) are written in base $6$ notation. How many of these will contain zero's?

Tags: contest-math, number-systems

Now I know that any number in decimal system which is divisible by the base $6$ will have a $0$ in the unit's place when that number in the decimal system will be converted into base $6$. This gives me a count of total $25$ numbers. 
Now I know that there are other numbers in the decimal system which I have left in the previous count of $25$ which when converted into base $6$ notation will have $0$ apart from the unit's place too. How can I count those? What concept I am missing here? Please help me on this !!!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: The analysis/algorithm for enumerating the number of *zeroes* is **independent of the base**.  That is, ask the same question for a number $n$, written in base $(10)$, and conjure a formula that applies to base $(10)$.  Then, adjust/generalize the formula to apply to base $(k)$ for $k \in \Bbb{Z}_{\geq 2}.$

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $150_{10} = 410_{6}$.
- How many numbers have a 0 in the units place?
- How many numbers have a 0 in the tens place, and a non-0 in the units place?
- Hence, the total is $ 4\times 6 + 1 + 4\times 5 = 45$.

Comment: How many numbers have a $0$ in the units place? $\Rightarrow$ I have already found this as I have mentioned in my solution approach. It is 25.
I am not able to find the the numbers which have $0$ in other places apart from the units place.

Comment: @Ganit 1) Show that the only other place the number can have a 0 is in the tens place. 2) For such numbers, how many are there? How many possibilities are there for the hundreds digit? for the units digit?    (IE See above)